# Alternating stylesheet using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

http://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/

Can anybody help me switch stylesheets using the above but with radios rather than anchors?

The below isn't working for me:

```
<input type="radio" name="setStyle" id="default" value="default" checked>
<input type="radio" name="setStyle" id="night" value="night">

(function () {
    $("input[name=setStyle]").click(function () {
        setActiveStyleSheet(this.value)
    });
})();
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Is the event being called?

Comment: How can I check? Developer Tools isn't showing up anything

Comment: add an alert into the functions to see if it gets called.

Comment: My guess is you are adding the events before the elements are rendered in the page. But with the context you gave, it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody,

Problem was solved simply by changing the `click` event to `change`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() 
{
    $("input[name=setStyle]").click(function () {
        setActiveStyleSheet(this.value)
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqq4s/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Check console for error. I've downloaded the project and checked your snippet. Assuming that it says that $ is not defined like it did to me, you do not need to register click handlers with [immediately invoked function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), but you should do it when document is ready, which would be done like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name=setStyle]").click(function () {
        setActiveStyleSheet(this.value)
    });
});
```